# How do I tell Resharper that my IEnumerable method removes nulls?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, static-analysis

Given the following code, Resharper will correctly warn me about a possible `NullReferenceException` on `foo.Bar` because there could be null elements in the enumerable:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = GetFoos();
var bars = foos.Select(foo => foo.Bar);
```

One way to satisfy the static analyzer is to explicitly exclude nulls:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = GetFoos().Where(foo => foo != null);
```

I find myself typing `.Where(x => x != null)` a lot, so I wrapped it up in an extension method, and now I can do the following:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = GetFoos().NotNull();
```

The problem is that Resharper doesn't know that `NotNull()` strips out nulls. Is there a way I can teach Resharper about this fact? In general, is there a way to tell Resharper that an `IEnumerable`-returning method will never have nulls in it (so that I can just annotate `GetFoos()` directly)?

I know I can use [the `NotNullAttribute`](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#NotNullAttribute) to tell Resharper that the enumerable itself is not null, but I can't find one that speaks about the *contents* of the enumerable.

**Edit:** The extension method looks exactly as you'd expect:

```
[NotNull]
public static IEnumerable<T> NotNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{   
    return enumerable.Where(x => x != null);
}
```

Comment: I don't use resharper. But if it does know that `foo != null` prevents a `NullReferenceException`, why does it not know that `NotNull` also skips null-foos? Can you also show `NotNull`?

Comment: @Tim they have some rules built-in the plugin, so it knows what `.Where(...)` does for instance, and the analysis engine can act accordingly. But it doesn't delve inside user methods, because solving this in the general case would be equivalent to solving the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Sadly, I don't think there's a way to annotate this particular rule... `[ContractAnnotation("??")]` may have been a solution but there's no syntax for enumerables either.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't know, but I suspect it's because the analyzer doesn't do deep method inspection to determine where nullability was last checked. I know that Resharper makes other interesting mistakes in this area -- for example, if I filter out nulls with `.Where`, and then immediately chain an `.OrderBy`, Resharper seems to lose the knowledge that nulls have been filtered out.

Comment: If you know that your code works, why bother with ReSharper flagging a warning? Just override the warning for your code in ReSharper if it annoys you...

Comment: @cseder Because this is one example of dozens in my code base. I don't want to just disable static analysis warnings on a case-by-case basis, I want to teach the analyzer what is correct.

Comment: Oh. Well, I'm obviously not as an advanced coder as you, because in my projects, I'm the one that makes the mistakes and ReSharper fixes it... ;-)

Comment: Related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-376091

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`ItemNotNullAttribute`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.2/Reference__Code_Annotation_Attributes.html#ItemNotNullAttribute) which tells ReSharper that no items in a collection can ever be `null`.

Comment: Excellent! Looks like they added that in 2016 -- so happy.

Answer (score 1):

One way as you stated is to use [NotNull] attribute which instruct Resharper engine to stop checking for null reference error for that particular variable.

Or else if you don't want to use that attribute you can optionally use the comments

```
// ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
        var bars = foos.Select(foo => foo.Bar);
// ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException
```

To make a point to this question, Resharper cannot traverse through statement's runtime computational values so it can make a judgement that it cannot be null.

Comment: The `NotNull` attribute will only verify that the *enumerable* is not null, it will not verify that the *results* of the enumerable are not null. Also, as stated in the comments above, I do not want to repeatedly disable null reference checking every time I use an enumerable.